# How Is It Possible to Access WebService Created on a Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library, asp.net-4.5

I first created a web service in ASP.net project, and then moved its code to a class library to a CSharp(.cs) file.

I also added an implementation of "IHttpHandlerFactory" in this newly created class so that I could register this service on web.config file:

```
public class Test: WebService, IHttpHandlerFactory
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string Hello(string world)
    {
        return "Hello " + world;
    }

    private static WebServiceHandlerFactory wshf = new WebServiceHandlerFactory();
    private static MethodInfo coreGetHandlerMethod = typeof(WebServiceHandlerFactory).GetMethod("CoreGetHandler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHandler(System.Web.HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
    {
        return (IHttpHandler)coreGetHandlerMethod.Invoke(wshf, new object[] { GetType(), context, context.Request, context.Response });
    }

    public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
    {

    }
}
```

and registered it in web.config:

```
<add name="TestService" path="TestService.asmx" verb="*" type="MyApp.Library.Test, MyApp.Library, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I can access it here:

```
http://localhost:8090/TestService.asmx
```

and it works fine when using the browser.

I had the previously working ajax call. I only had to change the url of the service:

```
/TestService.asmx
```

Now when the service is called using ajax, an error is produced:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

I do have

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

in the jQuery Ajax Call. After spending hours in frustration, I found a link to this page, which actually addressed this issue:

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/webservices.html

I do not want to add an extra dependency to spring.net for this task since I am already using castle windsor.

**How is it possible to access a webservice which was created on a class library project and registered in web.config, in as ASP.net web page?**

Comment: I think that you should be `consuming the webservice` not moving the code personally to a class library any way in order to access a WebService from a Class library you would need to consume that `WebService` `by adding a new reference ->advanced->WebService`
then you need to browse to and or type in the exact url of where you have the .asmx file.. here is a good link to read to make things easier
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prvn_131971/chapter-31creating-web-services/ also since you are using JSON there is an even simpler video on youtube for consuming Linq2Sql webservice

Comment: I am not consuming web service from class library but exposing one from it.

Comment: the same principal applies I am exposing one I just created yesterday.. and I create a little console application to step thru and debug it and it works flawlessly I can even test it locally by launching it from a project where I've created an empty website..then added a new item-> selected `webservice` and add in my [webmethod]...etc works like a charm Like I said if you are exposing it why do you feel the need to add it to a Class Library.. unless it's a `WCF` web service application but still  I think you need to understand how to consume a webservice

Comment: there is a much simpler way to do a webservice that sends back results in `json` format and looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel in my opinion..

Comment: I know how to create a web service. :)

Comment: that's good to know.. then if you know how to then you should in theory know how to create an `Instance` to a `Library` and consume the webservice from there..what am I missing here...?

Comment: Please read the question again. I am not consuming a webserive from class library. I am creating a webservice from class library. Registering the handler in web.config and using it in the UI.

Comment: `Ahha` ok when you changed the path.. do you have an option to `Update Web Reference` in your project ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69923/discussion-between-nick-binnet-and-methodman).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69924/discussion-between-nick-binnet-and-methodman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question so that anyone who encounters this problem would not have to bang their head against the wall. It seems that WebService created on a class library project (.net Framework 4.5.1) would **ignore** the parameter:

```
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json
```

Even when you specify JSON as the response format, it will still respond with an XML object.

So, I changed my requirement to solve the problem.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string Hello(string world)
{
    return "Hello " + world;
}
```

on the javascript part

```
$.post(url, function (result) {
    //result is an XML object
});
```